# Set Application Root in Web Application in bottle

Tags: python-2.7, bottle

How do I set Application Root for my application developed in bottle.

I have written my bottle application like this

```
app = Bottle()

@route(path = '/GetMain')
def get_main_page():
  return static_file(...)

app.run(host=socket.getfqdn(), port=8080)
```

By this above code, I can retreive my page like http://xxxx.com:8080/GetMain.
But if I want my code to be deployed under http://xxxx.com:8080/dashboard/GetMain, How do I change my application root.
I don't want to change all my URL's and reative paths

Comment: How are you deploying your application? mod_wsgi, gunicorn, ...?

Comment: I'm using the inbuilt server to deploy. I run the application like python filename.py on command line

Comment: You can do it easily using a web server (nginx or apache2). Is that an option for you ? If it's the case I'll post a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount it by specifying the prefix.

Here is a working example snippet.

```
import socket
from bottle import route, default_app


@route(path = '/GetMain')
def get_main_page():
  # Commenting out the below line for testing this snippet.
  # return static_file(...)
  return "Hello World"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = default_app()
    app.mount('/dashboard', app)
    app.run(host=socket.getfqdn(), port=8080)
```

Please note that I have tested this with python 3.5